# Does one fulfill the obligation of leining in Shul if he repeated words, i.e., said some words twice?

Tags: halacha

Does one fulfill leining if he repeated words as long as they were all said correctly?

Comment: As in saying the word twice or as someone else reading it to him and repeating after them?

Comment: saying word twice

Comment: Perhaps it’s a lichatchila vs. bedieved thing

Comment: I'd like to help you but I don't really understand what you're asking. Leaning publicly from a Torah scroll? Reading the parasha by yourself? Prayer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it’s permitted.
Repeating words is considered going back and starting anew, rather than saying the words twice.